# Windows 10 install: 'Something went wrong'

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 10 Home using VirtualBox on my Mac (although I shouldn't think the issue will be Mac related).

I *think* I've installed it anyway, but whenever I start up the machine it gives me the following error:

> **Something went wrong**.
>
> You can try again, or skip for now
>
> OOBEREGION

This is after having been starting at the 'Just a moment...' screen for about 10 minutes.

I read online that it can sometimes be fixed by simply restarting your machine, I've tried that a number of times but to no avail. I've also clicked the 'try again' button but no luck with that either.

Can anyone see what the issue is? I could try installing it again, but I could see that just being a lot of effort and probably won't resolve the issue.

Comment: What version of Win10? 1809 seems to have had a bug that 1803 didn't. idk about anything later.

Comment: This [article](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/ooberegion/) seems to have a basic suggestion on how to fix this. Also this [tenforums post](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-insider/118225-insider-isos-cant-get-past-oobe-stage.html). Another forum suggestion was to only install Windows for the US region.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I can confirm the fix to enable the Administrator account works. The real question is [why](https://superuser.com/questions/1575027/why-is-the-oobekeyboard-ooberegion-bug-fixed-or-worked-around-by-enabling-th).