# Why is the OOBEKEYBOARD / OOBEREGION bug fixed (or worked around) by enabling the default administrator account?

Tags: windows-10, installation, administrator, bug

MS has some (nonworking) advice for working around this issue [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020048/windows-oobe-fails-when-you-start-a-new-windows-based-computer-for-the). In my experience, you can click "try again" until you're blue in the face, it will never work.

The real workaround that worked for me is [found elsewhere](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/ooberegion/), which is to enable the built-in administrator account and create a user account manually.

```
net user Administrator /active:yes
net user /add your_user_name your_password
net localgroup administrators user_name /add
cd %windir%\system32\oobe
msoobe.exe
```

Then poweroff. And finally disable the password-less admin account after installation (with `net user Administrator /active:no`).

My question is: **why does the latter/real workaround work?** Where exactly is the bug in the MS OOBE scripts?

By the way, I've only experienced it on single-core machines while installing 1809 LTSC.  I did not experience it on VMs though (even single-core), as [other people did](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90707), but only on real (and pretty slow) hardware.

Comment: Only Microsoft can answer this.

Comment: @Moab: the working fix was not created by MS. So somewhat has figured out what is wrong.